# Авторизация на html

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Всем привет! Есть страница где при вводе логина и пароля (верного) должно отобразиться сообщение "вход выполнен" и записать например дату и время в файл .txt когда это произошло.
Если ввести неправильный логин и пароль и нажать вход. То соответственно сообщение "вход не выполнен"
и тоже запись события в .txt файл.

Сам логин пароль типо должен быть зашит в коде.

P.S. Может кто помочь допилить?!

html + css (без javascript'a - не использовать)

Запись в файл .txt http://www.cyberforum.ru/php/thread1848219.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <form id="loginForm" action="" method="post">

    <div class="field">
      <label>Имя пользователя:</label>
      <div class="input"><input type="text" name="" value="" id="login" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <a href="#" id="forgot">Забыли пароль?</a>
      <label>Пароль:</label>
      <div class="input"><input type="password" name="" value="" id="pass" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="submit">
      <button type="submit">Войти</button>
      <label id="remember"><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" /> Запомнить меня</label>
    </div>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

и сss

```
body {
  background: #E8EEF0 url(bg.gif);
}

#loginForm {
  width: 290px;
  padding: 24px 24px 0;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  background: #FEFEFE;
  border: 1px solid #CAD8DE;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  font: 14px/18px Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}

#loginForm .field {
  margin: 0 0 18px;
}

#loginForm .field label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 11px;
}

#loginForm .field .input {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#loginForm .field input {
  font: 12px Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  width: 262px;
  padding: 9px 13px;
  border: 1px solid #D2D9DC;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 6px #EBEBEB, 0 0 0 5px #F7F9FA;
  outline: none;
}

#loginForm .field input:focus {
  border-color: #B7D4EA;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 6px #EBEBEB, 0 0 4px #D0E6F6, 0 0 0 5px #F2F8FC;
}

#forgot {
  float: right;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ababab;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#forgot:hover {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#loginForm .submit {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px -24px 0;
  padding: 22px 24px;
  background: #F0F5F7;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDE0E8;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #FFF, inset -1px -1px #F7FAFB, inset 1px 0 #F7FAFB;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#remember {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#remember input {
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#loginForm .submit button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #98CCE7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #7DB0CC;
  border-left: 1px solid #8CBFD9;
  border-right: 1px solid #8CBFD9;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  font: bold 13px Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #D4EBF7, 0 1px 3px #B8BEBE;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #badff3 0%, #7acbed 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #badff3), color-stop(100%, #7acbed));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #badff3 0%, #7acbed 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #badff3 0%, #7acbed 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #badff3 0%, #7acbed 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #badff3 0%, #7acbed 100%);
  background-color: #9FD7F0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  outline: none;
}

#loginForm .submit button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0
}
```

Comment: `html` - это не язык программирования, по этому никак нельзя на чистом `html` сделать вход и тем-более запись.

Comment: без скриптов, только средствами сервера: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F =)

Comment: Авторизация не производится HTML/CSS/JavaScript ... это все клиентская часть.

Comment: @radriges начните изучать https://www.php.net/manual/ru/

Comment: @Михаил Ребров, у меня имитация авторизации. тут нет авторизации априори. просто под то что выше написал

Comment: вашу задачу невозможно реализовать только на html+css

Comment: Нужен хотя бы ещё javascript, раз уж это имитация. html+css это только внешний вид, разметка.

Comment: @Sheridan, напишите пример с js. под мое задание.